# iwlist scan: About the address? Is it unique? What kind of address is it?

Tags: linux

```
#: iwlist wlan00 scanning
wlan0    Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 16:76:02:7D:A5:25
          .....
```

I was wondering what that address is? And is it unique?

That is what the Wireless tools iwlib.h refers to right?

```
  int       has_ap_addr;
  sockaddr  ap_addr;        /* Access point address */
```

I am just looking for a unique identifier for the results that appear. Is that one?

Thanks

Comment: It's a mac address and you can read the following - http://superuser.com/questions/268006/are-mac-addresses-unique-when-coming-out-of-the-factory

Comment: I don't know if I should create another question, but I'll ask here for now. Why does it print out a number like "71731" when I print it like this? 

printf("MAC is: %d\n", result->ap_addr);

Does it need to be converted first I assume? Any tips?

Comment: `%d` is for printing an `int`. `result->ap_addr` is not an `int`. printf doesn't have sockaddr-to-string formatting built in; you need to do it before calling printf somehow. The first thing to do would be to find out the value of `result->ap_addr.sa_family` so you know what kind of sockaddr it is.

Comment: printf("%d\n", result->ap_addr.sa_family); gives 1 as output. what does that mean. Is it AF_INET or AF_INET6 ? In any case, I can check with a simple if statement.

Comment: That's strange. `AF_UNIX` is 1. I was expecting `AF_PACKET` or something like it. (It shouldn't be `AF_INET` either; that would be an IP address.) I don't know enough about iw to figure out what this means.

Comment: This is the type ap_addr is in iwlib.h ... sockaddr ap_addr;

Comment: This is how iwlist.c prints it out:
printf("          Cell %02d - Address: %s\n", state->ap_num,
      iw_saether_ntop(&event->u.ap_addr, buffer));